# Influence of debugging on runtime complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm curious about how much complexity is introduced to an algorithm while it's being debugged. Is there a general theory for optimal debugging algorithms and theoretically optimal debugging performance?

The curiosity is a consequence of the following question: If I mean debugging to be the process of making information available to the programmer during the runtime of the program, then we'd call a total debugging algorithm to be one that made all information available to read during the run time. Would this necessarily double the run time?

I'd also like to pose and open ended question for discussion sake.

What are your thoughts about the relationship between the introduced complexity from debugging algorithms (using the definition for debugging I describe) and uncertainty as it exists in observing the real world as in physics?

In your opinion is there a strong or weak correlation between the concept of observational biases in the respective cases?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Open-ended questions and invitations to discussion are normally not suitable for this site; see our [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I suspect this is not the sort of problem that theoretical running time analysis will be very useful for adding much insight on.

Theoretical analysis is very useful when there are algorithmic techniques that make a major difference in scaling (e.g., $O(n)$ vs $O(n^2)$).  Theoretical running time analysis is not very useful when you care about constant factors.

The cost of debugging is a constant factor, which is ignored in asymptotic analysis.  I suspect that the costs of debugging are driven primarily by engineering concerns, which are typically abstracted in theoretical running time analysis.

One theoretical result that might be of interest to you: it is possible to keep track of all past states of the program (see, e.g., [time-travel debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel_debugging)) by using [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).  Persistent data structures are known to impose at most a logarithmic overhead in running time.  The practical cost of time-travel debugging might typically be less than that in practice, for a number of reasons that are beyond the scope of theoretical algorithms.